# Is there a way to read/access emails or inbox in Android programmatically?

Tags: android, email

Is there a way to read/access emails or inbox in Android programmatically?

Comment: Why is the title "Iphone" when the question is on Android?

Comment: I dunno. Edited it to 'android' instead.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I am aware, there is no way to programmatically access emails through the default Gmail application. Your best option is to find some POP or IMAP library, and integrate that into your application. By entering their email information you can then get their emails for that mailbox in your own application.