# Get email from built-in email application in Android

Tags: android, email

Is there a way to get emails from built-in Android email application. If so, how can i achieve that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695137/android-access-or-read-email-programatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its not allowed due to the Private policies. as the mails are the private content to the user. I tried to explore it about 6 months back but did not got any solution and stuck @ this privacy policy point.

Comment: So.. if we can't use something existant, than we can build our own application. I succeeded to get emails from gmail using pop3 with help of "JavaEmail" for android.

Comment: Thats the same solution I adapted at my time